# SQL Trigger code run without error but no Out put

Tags: sql-server, ssms, database-trigger

I have two data base in same server TEST1 and TEST2

In TEST1 i have a table called dbo.TB_EVENT_LOG
columns are

```
[nEventLogIdn]
[nDateTime]
[nReaderIdn]
[nEventIdn]
[nUserID]
[nIsLog]
[nTNAEvent]
[nIsUseTA]
[nType]
```

and in Test2 i have a table called dbo.AccessLog
columns are

```
[RCDID]
[EmployeeID]
[LogDate]
[LogTime]
[TerminalID]
[InOut]
```

What i want to do is fire a trigger when ever any data is inset or update to test1 dbo.TB_EVENT_LOG. And insert the data from specific columns of dbo.TB_EVENT_LOG( nDateTime, nReaderIdn, nUserID) to dbo.AccessLog (LogDate, TerminalID, EmployeeID)

The trigger running in dbo.TB_EVENT_LOG Table

Here is the trigger code i have so far

```
USE [test1]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[coveter]    Script Date: 11/18/2018 2:25:13 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      
-- Create date: 18/11/2018
-- Description: 
-- =============================================
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[coveter] 
   ON  [dbo].[TB_EVENT_LOG] 
   AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    insert into test2.dbo.AccessLog
    (
        [LogDate],
        [LogTime],
        [TerminalID],
        [EmployeeID]
    )

    select [nDateTime], [nDateTime], [nReaderIdn],[nUserID] from dbo.TB_EVENT_LOG

END
```

The Code run without any error but i couldn't get the result i want. Any help?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: *"i couldn't get the result i want"* So what did happen then? You forgot to tell us that. Why is what did happen different to what you expected? The trigger, as it stands, would insert details of **every** row in the `TB_EVENT_LOG` into the `AccessLog` table. I *assume* that isn't what you want, but what is?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, What i want is When ever any new row of data in inserted to the TB_EVENT_LOG the same date to be inserted in to AccessLog.

Comment: Then why do you have the trigger on `DELETE` too? No rows will be inserted then. What about `UPDATE`, that's not a new roe inserted, so should that be included too?

Comment: 'DML triggers use the deleted and inserted logical (conceptual) tables. They are structurally similar to the table on which the trigger is defined, that is, the table on which the user action is tried. The deleted and inserted tables hold the old values or new values of the rows that may be changed by the user action' - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 - I see no reference to INSERTED or DELETED in your trigger.

Comment: Your script refers to 2 separate databases. In which database are you checking to see if the trigger is working?

Comment: Trigger is created in test1 dbo.TB_EVENT_LOG. i am checking the test2 database dbo.AccessLog